# What does cache value signifies in UpdateTip log messages?

Tags: bitcoind

```
UpdateTip: new best=0000000027effeeafbf56c6c9de19f7d8f5b96227b2b4e85c6f6033220866f0d  height=221  log2_work=39.298291  tx=46374  date=2015-11-06 12:02:46 progress=1.000000  cache=3.0MiB(10114tx)
```

What is the significance of `cache=3.0MB` in above mentioned UpdateTip log drom debug.log ?

Answer (score 2):

It's describing how much of the allocated UTXO cache you are using. You can adjust how much maximum memory Bitcoin Core uses for this and others with the `dbcache` parameter, the higher the limit in megabytes the higher the performance to a certain degree.